# Hibernate Mapping thinking error

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a 2 database tables. First has trades in it. Each Trade has an ID. This ID is also found in my 2nd table. the 2nd table contains charges, but my first table has no information about the charges. now i have to get all charges which are connected to 1 trade by hibernate mapping, but i don't want to have it in both directions.

Trade Class:

```
public class Trade {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long tradeTag;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "VIE_CHARGES", joinColumns = 
    @JoinColumn(name="TRADE"))
    private List<Charge> charges;
}
```

Charge class:

```
public class Charge implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String chargeType;
    @Id
    @Column(name="TRADE")
    private Long tradeTag;
}
```

In charge class, i don't want to hold any information about the trade, but in trade class a list of all charges for the trade. I would be very happy to get a solution here, as i have really no idea how to do it.

view for charge:

```
create view VIE_CHARGES as 
select CHRG_TYPE AS CHARGETYPE
,TRAD_TAG AS TRADE
from TRADE_CHARGE
```

view for trade:

```
create VIEW VIE_TRADE AS 
select TRAD_TAG as ID
from TRADE
```

error is:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2123)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1911)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:319)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2327)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder$LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializer.initialize(LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2150)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:567)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:249)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:563)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:161)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:146)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:249)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:145)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261)
>     at
>   com.mainfirst.emma.archive.trade.rims.TestDataBaseconnection.testTradeDao(TestDataBaseconnection.java:28)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: **Invalid
>   column name 'charges_TRADE'**.    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
>     ... 50 more

Comment: Use @JoinColumn in Trade class  with reference to foreign key column in Charge class

Comment: @rathna yeah, but i dont want the charge to hold any information about the trade if possible (don't think it is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the charge objects do not need an own lifecycle (no own identifier, not referenced by multiple trades, should not exist alone and should be and deleted with it's trade) you could map it as `@ElementCollection` of value types (`@Embeddable`).

The mapped table and id column name could be set by `@CollectionTable` and `@JoinColumn` annotations. It's defaults are "trade_charges" and "trade_id".

The `@OrderColumn` annotation is just a little performance boost, you only need it when you face a lot of changes to the collection. It adds an index column to the trade_charges table to identify rows on update / delete statements.

For example the Trade:

```
@Entity
public class Trade {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long tradeTag;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "charges", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID"))
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Charge> charges;

}
```

And the Charge:

```
@Embeddable
public class Charge {

    private String chargeType;

}
```

Comment: with your solution i am getting a invalid column name error on charges_Trade. any idea how i could delete the `charges_` in the name?

Comment: Hm. There should be no such column. The charges table should contain two columns starting with charge..., that should be charge_type and charges_order. Which database is in use?

Comment: its an ms sql server. i work with views as no data should be changed by any means. therefore i created some views to map the classes to. if i change the list name to anything, the column name in the error changes to the same value

Comment: So there is a given database structure (containing data) and you cannot change it? Then you have to adjust the names in the mapping according to your existing columns and remove the @OrderColumn, because this would add another column.

Comment: yeah i can't change it. but i can't seem to change the names properly enough. always getting the invalid column name error. column name is always list name_charge id

Comment: So it claims about the id column in charges table? Maybe "id" does not exist. What's the trade identifier column in your charge table? Something like trade_tag?" Then you would have to use something like @JoinColumn(name="tradeTag")"

Comment: Maybe you can paste your schema and the complete error message and we can have a look.

Comment: posted everything needed. updated class codes to match your example

Comment: in my example the charge class only contains: `private String chargeType;` you don't need ids and the trade column if you have a value type

Comment: so hibernate is automatically mapping the charges to the trades by the tradeTag? because the tradeTag is the only way to identify the charges connected to each trade

Comment: Sure, it's using the identifier of the parent to identify childs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141952/discussion-between-xtremebaumer-and-kevin-peters).

Answer (score 1):

In hibernate it is the best approach to use bidirectional @OneToMany and keep both sides of relation in sync. Smth like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    private Set<Phone> phones=new HashSet<Phone>();
//getters and setters
public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
        phone.setPerson(this);
        phones.add(phone);
    }

    public void removePhone(Phone phone) {
        phone.setPerson(null);
        phones.remove(phone);
    }
}
```

And phone entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Phone")
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "`number`")
    private String number;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
    private Person person;
```

Read docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many

Comment: that is exactly what i don't want to do

Answer (score 0):

So in the docs to @OneToMany there was an example of which i think it fits my needs as much as possible.

Solution i am working with now:

```
public class Trade {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long tradeTag;
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="trade")
    private List<Charge> charges;
}

public class Charge implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String chargeType;
    @Id
    @Column(name="TRADE")
    private Long tradeTag;
}
```

if someone has any better idea feel free to share with me